# CSV Data format for Bulk Load in Amazon Neptune

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-neptune

I have two CSV files that I have to Bulk load in Amazon Neptune.

1. Vertex Data - [-Node Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFf69.png)
2. Edge Data [-Edge Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAvLz.png)

I am trying to load this database in Amazon Neptune DB to create a Knowledge Graph on Edge Data,
But after completing all the required steps when I load the data, the LOAD_FAILED response comes up.

Is there any specific format in which I have to upload the CSV sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Neptune's bulk loader provides a means to load data into a Neptune cluster from Amazon S3 via the following formats:

- For Property Graph data, Neptune supports a specific CSV file format with certain required headers:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-format-gremlin.html
- For Resource Description Framework (RDF) data, Neptune supports the standard file formats of rdfxml, nquads, ntriples, and turtle file formats.